# The compiler shows a warning from this code

Tags: c, string, pointers, data-structures

My compiler (clang) shows this message:

> expected-warning{{format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*) [5]'}}

From the following code (greetings program):

```
/*
 * Program: gretting2.c
 * Utility: Display a greeting with your name.
 * Author:  Adrián Garro.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char name[0];

    printf("-------------------\n");
    printf("Write your name: \n");
    printf("-------------------\n");

    scanf("%s", &name);
    /*
    expected-warning{{format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*) [5]'}}
    */

    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Hello %s, nice to meet you\n",name);
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
}
```

How can I fix it? I would appreciate if somebody can help me.