# scanf() works despite 0-length buffer and compiler warning. What is going on?

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf

My compiler (clang) shows this message:

> ```
> 11:17:warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has
>       type 'char (*)[0]' [-Wformat]
>     scanf("%s", &name);
>            ~~   ^~~~~
> 1 warning generated.
> ```

from the following code (greetings program):

```
/*
 * Program: gretting2.c
 * Utility: Display a greeting with your name.
 * Author:  Adrián Garro.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char name[0];

    printf("-------------------\n");
    printf("Write your name: \n");
    printf("-------------------\n");

    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Hello %s, nice to meet you\n",name);
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
}
```

What is actually going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I know that this is basic, but I'm a recently computer science student.

Comment: This code works, the only problem is that the compiler shows a warning, for that reason this code is only a for a review.

Comment: What do you want to do with an array of size 0?

Comment: I think you can delete the question here? Or whats the difference? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27789854/3933332

Comment: two changes, use a large enough value for the array dimension of name perhaps name[64] and in your scanf remove the address of operator or use &name[0].

Comment: the code only works if scanf doesn't use the stack, or if the stack  goes downwards through memory address... but i don't want to explain all of that if this is one of your first programs. even then its implementation dependent whether it works, and there will always be some length of string where you will see some memory corruption (possibly a stack overflow! :)).

Comment: @Rizier123: It no longer can be deleted by the OP, but it can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code exhibits "undefined behavior."  This means anything could happen.  Anything.

You are passing a zero-length array to `scanf()`.  Also, you are not passing the array length in the format string.  This results in a buffer overflow vulnerability (always, in the case of a zero-length target array).

You need something like this:

```
char name[51];
scanf("%50s", name);
```

Note the `%50s` now specifies the size of the target array (less one, to leave room for the null terminator!), which avoids buffer overflow.  You still need to check the return value of `scanf()`, and whether the input `name` is actually too long (you wouldn't want to truncate the user's input without telling them).

If you're on Linux, check out the tool called `valgrind`.  It is a runtime memory error detector (among other things), and can sometimes catch errors like this for you (and much less obvious ones, which is the main point).  It's indispensable for many C programmers.

Comment: I'm using OS X Yosemite; but i will try Linux with the tool that you mentioned.

Comment: Isn't this %.50s in the standard? or am i misremembering... other than that better answer than mine i'd say by avoiding having to touch the 'hackiness' of the C array implementation and venture into memory addresses and pointer arithmetic...

Answer (score 4):

In order to understand this, you have to understand what `scanf` is doing. `scanf` in this case is reading a string from stdin, and placing it into a buffer that you give it. **It does not allocate that space for you, or detect overflow.** You need to allocate sufficient space for your string. As it stands now, you are allocating *zero* space for your string, so everything is an overflow. This is a major bug.

Say instead of `char[0]`, you did `char[40]`, as another user suggests.What if the user of your program writes more than 40 characters? This results in undefined behavior. Essentially, it will write to memory you don't want it to write to. It might cause a segfault, it might result in crucial memory getting overwritten, or it might happen to work. This is a weakness of `scanf.` Look into `fgets.` You tell it the size of your buffer, and input will be truncated to fit.

Of course, that has nothing to do with your warning. You're getting a warning because referring to the name of an array is the same as referring to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `name <==> &(name[0])`. Taking a pointer to this is like taking a pointer to a pointer, i.e. `&name <==> &&(name[0])`. Since `scanf` is looking for an argument of type `char*`, and it's getting a pointer to that, the type checker complains.

Comment: Nice explanation. But I noticed the array dimension of 5 in the warning. Bit curious where it is coming from.  **format specifies type 'char ' but the argument has type 'char () [5]'***

Comment: There is a difference between an arrays and pointers, but it's a subtle one. The only real difference I can think of is their behavior with the `sizeof` operator. The %s format definitely wants type `char *`, and referring to the name of the array will get you that. When OP used the reference operator on it, it seems to have interpreted that as an array of five pointers. I don't know why that is. We'd have to check the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

Just change this:

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

to:

```
scanf("%39s", name);
```

and this:

```
char name[0];
```

to:

```
char name[40];
```

Also to you have to end it with a '\0' with:

```
name[39] = '\0';
```

Comment: Into a zero-length char array? ;)

Comment: It works! What is the theoretical explanation of this?

Comment: He just fixed each of your mistakes. (Well, sort of.)

Comment: This is not safe use of `scanf`. If the user types more than 40 characters, it will overwrite random stack memory. Change `%s` to `%39s`. Still, upvoting as the rest is good info.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Thanks! (forgot that one, changed it also)

Comment: I believe it's not mandatory to add `name[39] = '\0'`. If reading from `stdin` using `scanf`, a `'\0'` will be added at the end of the string after the input. For example, if I write `StackOverflow` through the keyboard, this will be actually given as `StackOverflow\0`.

Comment: An array name is not a pointer, an array name decays to a pointer.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks you wrote my minds a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how robust you want this to be you will want to reconsider the approach. I guess the first thing is whether you understand the type you are using when declaring `char name[ 0 ]`. this is a 'zero-sized' array of byte-sized characters. This is a confusing thing and it wouldn't surprise me if its behaviour differs across compilers...

The actual warning being complained by the compiler is that the type doesn't match. If you take the address of the first character in the array you can get rid of that (i.e. use `&( name[ 0 ] )` in the `scanf` call). The address of `name` is its location on the stack - it just so happens that the array implementation uses that same location to store the array data, and `name` is treated differently by the compiler when used on its own so that the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element...

Using `char name[ 0 ]` leaves you open to causing memory corruption because there is nowhere for the string to be read, and implementation details may just luck out and allow this to work. One simple way to fix this is to replace 0 with a meaningful number which you take to the maximum length of the input string. Say 32 so that you have `char name[ 32 ]` instead... however this doesn't handle the case of an even longer string.

Since we live in a world of lots of memory and large stacks you can probably do `char name[ 4096 ]` and use 4KB of memory for the buffer and that will be absolutely fine for real world usage.

Now... if you want to be a little anal and handle pathological cases, like a user leaning on some keys whilst asleep for hours before pressing enter and adding some enormous 8000 character long string there are a few ways to handle that too with 'dynamic memory allocation', but that might be a bit beyond the scope of this answer.

---

As an aside, from what I understand `char foo[ 0 ]` is intentionally valid - it may have originated as a hack and has a confusing type, but is not uncommonly relied on for an old trick to create variable sized structs as described [in this page from the GCC online docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. char name[0]; ---> char name[100];
   /* You need to allocate some memory to store the name */

2.scanf("%s", &name);----> scanf("%s", name); 
/* scanf takes char* as an argument so you need to pass string name only. */

i don't think that scanf("%(length - 1)s", name); is needed.
Because %s is used to reads a string. This will stop on the first whitespace character reached, or at the specified field width (e.g. "%39s"), whichever comes first.

except these don't tend to be used as often. You, of course, may use them as often as you wish!

/

```
*
 * Program: gretting2.c
 * Utility: Display a greeting with your name.
 * Author:  Adrián Garro.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char name[100];

    printf("-------------------\n");
    printf("Write your name: \n");
    printf("-------------------\n");

    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Hello %s, nice to meet you\n",name);
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the correct way is

```
scanf("%s", name);
        /* ^ no ampersand
```

and what is

```
char name[0];
```

you should specify a non-zero length and use it for `scanf` length specifier

```
scanf("%(length - 1)s", name);
        /*  ^ sunstitite with the value */
```

Answer (score 0):

there were several problems with the OPs posted code

the following fixes most of them

I includd comments to indicate where the problems are

int main ()
{

```
//char name[0];  // this did not allow any room for the name
char  name[100] = {'\0'}; // declare a 100 byte buffer and init to all '\0'

printf("-------------------\n");
printf("Write your name:, max 99 char \n"); // 99 allows room for nul termination byte
printf("-------------------\n");

//scanf("%s", &name);  // this has no limit on length of input string so can overrun buffer
if( 1 == scanf("%99s", name) )   // 1) always check returned value from I/O functions
                                 // 2) no '&' before 'name' because
                                 //    arrays degrade to pointer to array when variable
                                 //    name is used
                                 // 3) placed max size limit on format conversion string
                                 //    so input buffer 'name' cannot be overflowed
{ // then scanf failed
    perror( "scanf failed for name" );
    return(-1);  // indicate error
}

// implied else, scanf successful

printf("------------------------------------\n");
printf("Hello %s, nice to meet you\n",name);
printf("------------------------------------\n");

return(0); // indicate success
```

} // end function: main

Answer (score -1):

You are reading a "string", thus the correct way is:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

Why does the compiler complain? When you provide an argument in `scanf`, you provide the memory location of the variable. For example:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

`&x` is `int *`, i.e., a pointer to an integer, so `x` will get the correct value.

<s>When you read a string, you're actually reading many `char` variables together. To store them, you need a `char *` array; well, `name` is `char *` on its own, so no need to write `&name`. The latter is `char **`, i.e., a 2-dimensional array of `char`.</s>

By the way, you also need to allocate space for the characters to read. Thus, you have to write `char name[20]` (or any other number). You also need to provide a `return 0;` in your `int main()`.

Comment: @2501 Thank you for the advice. Could you tell me please which part is wrong, exactly, so that I can look it up?